# Location data storage (points, grouping by distance etc) - Best Practices and Recommended Solutions

Tags: sql, database, google-maps, gis, geospatial

I have come across a problem that I 've never solved before but I find it frequently implemented in various apps so I would like to ask if there is a common way to solve it. I have a set of analytics data each representing some logging action (i.e. info, warn etc). Each of this items has a location and a type (i.e. action). There can be millions of these items per area (depending on the area size or map zoom).

I am looking for the best way to store this set of data in my database. I am very comfortable with SQL Server but dont mind what db I have to use as long as it can handle the scalability requirements. If Amazon WS offers such a product or some other cloud solution then even better cause thats how we are planning to host this app. Google maps will be used to visualize the data.

Some requirements:

1. Be able to plot all data for a given map rectangle (a common google
   map interface with markers representing the logging actions)
2. Be able to zoom in/zoom out and get relevant data for the new map rectangle
3. Be able to "group" markers in one bigger marker if data are very close. For instance, if point A is 1 km away from point B and I am seeing a map of 10 km radius then I should see two independent points, A and B. But if I zoom out to 500 km radius then point A and B are too close to each other so I would like to group them in one marker. Hopefully that's possible.
4. If SQL Server is not a good solution then a free, very cheap or cloud-based storage solution should be recommended (no I cant afford an Oracle).

All the queries above should be able to come back within milliseconds or somehow to be cached. Queries will be of the kind: Get me all analytics data for the given map window with zoom of the given rectangle latitude/longitude.

Thanks,
Yannis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undertsood correctly, there are 2 sides to your question:

1- A Database System, that supports storage and lookup of spatial data. Many of the free/open source RDBMS have spatial extensions: [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gis-introduction.html) and Postgres ([PostGIS](http://www.postgis.org/)) in particular. Spatial data are stored like any other data with the addition of spatial geometry attribute, which describes the shape of your data instance (point, rectangle, polygon, ellipse, ...). You can query spatial data entities, with spatial filters. And of course, spatial queries support joints and unions and almost all kind of SQL constructs.

2- A client/server api that would support rendering of spatial data (with the usual functions such as zoom in, zoom out, pan, etc.), caching and drill-down. As far as I know, there isn't one api that support all these features together, out the box. But there are some interesting [apis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_geographic_information_systems_software) that you might want to investigate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - I will have a look at your suggestions. With regards to 1 I am not sure I understand the shape concept. Should I just store latitude and longitude?

Comment: The shape is basically the geometry of your spatial data instance. It can be a point, a line, a polygon, an ellipse or a composite. In your case it's a point with ( x = longitude, y = latitude ). And to that point you can attach whatever descriptive information makes sens for your domain object (logging, timestamp, etc.).